# Storm Topology going to Idle state, unable to read messages from kafkaSpout

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

My storm topology runs for certain time (let say 18h, 21h) then goes to Idle state. That Topology is not responding to messages sent by kafka. I have seen the logs I can't find out what is happening?

[image]

When Topology not responding to the Kafka Messages I am getting Logs:

> .ZkCoordinator [INFO] Task [7/8] Refreshing partition manager
>   connections
>       2016-03-30 02:59:15 s.k.DynamicBrokersReader [INFO] Read partition info from zookeeper:
>   GlobalPartitionInformation{partitionMap=  {0=IP:6667, 1=IP:6667,
>   2=IP:6667, 3=IP:6667, 4=IP:6667, 5=IP:6667, 6=IP:6667, 7=IP:6667}}
>       2016-03-30 02:59:15 s.k.KafkaUtils [INFO] Task [7/8] assigned [Partition{host=IP:6667, partition=6}]
>       2016-03-30 02:59:15 s.k.ZkCoordinator [INFO] Task [7/8] Deleted partition managers: []
>       2016-03-30 02:59:15 s.k.ZkCoordinator [INFO] Task [7/8] New partition managers: []
>       2016-03-30 02:59:15 s.k.ZkCoordinator [INFO] Task [7/8] Finished refreshing
>       2016-03-30 03:01:15 s.k.ZkCoordinator [INFO] Task [7/8] Refreshing partition manager connections
>       2016-03-30 03:01:15 s.k.DynamicBrokersReader [INFO] Read partition info from zookeeper:
>   GlobalPartitionInformation{partitionMap=  {0=IP:6667, 1=IP:6667,
>   2=IP:6667, 3=IP:6667, 4=IP:6667, 5=IP:6667, 6=IP:6667}
>       2016-03-30 03:01:15 s.k.KafkaUtils [INFO] Task [7/8] assigned [Partition{host=IP:6667, partition=6}]
>       2016-03-30 03:01:15 s.k.ZkCoordinator [INFO] Task [7/8] Deleted partition managers: []
>       2016-03-30 03:01:15 s.k.ZkCoordinator [INFO] Task [7/8] New partition managers: []
>       2016-03-30 03:01:15 s.k.ZkCoordinator [INFO] Task [7/8] Finished refreshing
>       2016-03-30 03:03:15 s.k.ZkCoordinator [INFO] Task [7/8] Refreshing partition manager connections
>       2016-03-30 03:03:15 s.k.DynamicBrokersReader [INFO] Read partition info from zookeeper: GlobalPartitionInformation{partitionMap=
>         {0=IP:6667, 1=IP:6667, 2=IP:6667, 3=IP:6667, 4=IP:6667, 5=IP:6667,
>   6=IP}
>       2016-03-30 03:03:15 s.k.KafkaUtils [INFO] Task [7/8] assigned [Partition{host=IP:6667, partition=6}]
>       2016-03-30 03:03:15 s.k.ZkCoordinator [INFO] Task [7/8] Deleted partition managers: []
>       2016-03-30 03:03:15 s.k.ZkCoordinator [INFO] Task [7/8] New partition managers: []
>       2016-03-30 03:03:15 s.k.ZkCoordinator [INFO] Task [7/8] Finished refreshing
>       2016-03-30 03:05:15 s.k.ZkCoordinator [INFO] Task [7/8] Refreshing partition manager connections

How can I trace the problem?

Below is ThreadDump for one of the Pid

```
Thread 26783: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=226 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=68, line=2082 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=122, line=1090 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=1, line=807 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=156, line=1068 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Compiled 
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)
Thread 26776: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2043 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=98, line=1085 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=1, line=807 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=156, line=1068 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Interpreted 
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)
Thread 26769: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2043 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take() @bci=28, line=209 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take() @bci=1, line=68 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop() @bci=10, line=781 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$400(org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl)                line=57 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call() @bci=4, line=275 (Interpreted frame)
```

Comment: Which version of storm are you using?

Comment: @JayaAnanthram Storm-0.9.3

Comment: Did you tried to get thread dump of all worker especially spout worker. Once upon a time I faced similar issue, after taking the tread dump I found a java code level deadlock while printing the log statements. So the spout worker was trapped into dead lock and it does not tried to consume message from topic even though the kafka has plenty number of pending messages. Thread dump can be taken by `jstack PID_OF_SPOUT_WORKER > dump.txt`. In the dump.txt you can find dead lock information at the end.

Comment: @JayaAnanthram I'm using RHEL how can i do thread dump

Comment: It is not concern about your OS. Go to `$JAVA_HOME/bin` and type `jstack PID_OF_SPOUT_WORKER > dump.txt`.  PID_OF_SPOUT_WORKER  is process id of your storm spout worker.

Comment: @JayaAnanthram, got it... I'm new to storm so lot of doubts. How to get PID of Spout_Worker.. If I do ps -ef | grep storm I am getting all the storm PID's how get particular PID

Comment: After clicking the topology in Storm UI you will be moved to the topology details UI where you can find the port for the spout (Under `Spouts (All time)` heading) then you can get the process ID for the port that is listening. Or else just try to get thread dump for all the workers and find whether deadlock exists in all the dump files.

Comment: And one more option is after finding the PID of spout workers (not sure whether you are having one or more spouts) just kill all the spout worker. The supervisor will start the spout worker again, once the worker get started it will consume the message from kafka until it get trapped into deadlock. If this work as my expectation, then I can say surely your spout is getting trapped into deadlock.

Comment: I got it . When i kill the process PID's supervisor is starting the processes and I am getting the messages again. How to solve the deadlock problem?

Comment: Can you please provide the thread dump of spout worker when it is trapped into deadlock? What are the jars that you are using for storm, which are related to log frame works? Need to analyze from your thread dump.

Comment: @JayaAnanthram I have edited my question with one pid thread dump .. to send all the the threaddumps is there any way attach files.

Comment: You cannot get every thing with a single question. Try to google... [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4637/please-add-a-system-to-allow-file-uploads-attached-to-questions-and-answers) I find a option to upload a snippet.

Comment: @JayaAnanthram thanks, I am able to trace the problem need to solve it

Comment: To solve you need to analyze the thread dump and need to figure out the fix for deadlock.

Comment: @JayaAnanthram..When I saw thread dump files I found the statement No dead locks found but when I kill any of the pid then spout starts receiving. What does it mean?

Comment: `When I saw thread dump files` what does it means? Did you analyzed all the thread dump of spout workers or did you analyzed some other worker thread dump? How many spout workers do you having? Without seeing the thread dump no one will help you.

Comment: @JayaAnanthram [http://filesave.me/file/131525/threadDump-tar-gz.html] here are the ThreadDump files of each pid. I had 2 workers.

Comment: Are you sure whether these are thread dump that has been taken when the storm was idle? Out of 8 files, what are the files that belongs to spout worker?

Comment: @JayaAnanthram All are related to spout taken from 2 brokers(server1 and server2) where on the same node there are 2 supervisors. I had given 8 workers to the topology. when I open spout stats it shows 6704,6706,6707,6708 and the pids thread dumps on those ports .